# GitHub Linguist does not see sub-folders?

Tags: github, github-linguist

So, I have a project that is around 80% Java and 20% Python. It is both by the number of lines of code and by their actual value.
However, this is the language breakdown that GitHub detects:
[Language Breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOxhb.png)

I assumed that it might have to do with that my structure of the repository is the following:

```
Main Folder
|--\Menu (contains a couple of .py files)
|--\CoreFiles (contains a .txt and .csv, both very short)
   |--\src (contains several .java files and .idea)
   |--\out (contains some other cascaded folders and .java files inside)
```

I tried adding a .gitattributes file and putting this code in there:

```
*.java linguist-language=Java
*.py linguist-language=Python
```

Nothing changed.
I am clueless. My last idea feels kinda dull, but I don't know what else is the problem: perhaps, the fact that .java files are somewhat deeper down the folder structure causes this?

Has anyone had this problem? How did you solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to install `github-linguist` locally and run `linguist --breakdown` in your repository?

Comment: I did not know that was an option. I will try, thank you